# calling function in a controller from a directive view, angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to use ng-click to call two functions, in the html for a directive.  The first function, 'checkUrl', is in the directives controller, and is working fine.

The second function, 'findUrl', is in the main app controller, and is not being fired.

HTML:

```
<div class="status" ng-click="checkUrl()">
    <b ng-click="checkUrl()">{{card.status}}</b>
</div>
<div ng-click="findUrl()" class="image">
    <img ng-src={{card.image}} alt="">
</div>
```

I have a couple of questions:

1) Is this because the two controllers have different scopes, and one can't access the other?

2) How can I get the directives view/html to invoke the main controllers function?

directive's controller:

```
$scope.checkUrl = function() {
    console.log("invoking checkUrl from the directive's controller.")
    asnService.showUrl();
};
```

application controller:

```
$scope.findUrl = function() {
    console.log("invoking findUrl from the app controller");
    asnService.showUrl();
};
```

Comment: Best practice is to not use `$scope` and use `controllerAs`. If you don't see an identifier before the function like `something.findUrl()` then it is an anti-pattern by today's Angular conventions.

Comment: yes they can have different scopes particularly if you declared isolated scope in directive. Show directive code

Comment: To answer your question, you can use $scope.$parent.findUrl() to access the scope variables on the parent scope of your directive.  Not necessarily recommended, but it works.

Comment: thanks @Scottie please post as answer so I can accept.

Comment: @elclanrs I will practice using controllerAs, will be posting a question about that shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you can use $scope.$parent.findUrl() to access the scope variables on the parent scope of your directive. Not necessarily recommended, but it works.

Comment: As a relative newbie to angular, I'd be interested to hear why this is not necessarily recommended. It seems like there are a lot of 'unspoken' no-no's with angular and the fact they usually aren't apparent to me says I am not appreciating the wider concepts.

Comment: @moosefetcher, the reason using $parent isn't recommended is that it tightly binds your child component to your parent.  It no longer becomes re-usabe because now there is a specific dependency to this variable.  In this case, now your parent controller MUST have a function called findUrl().  However, while not recommended, there are times when it's appropriate. I've used it $parent many times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is 3 ways:

**First**

if have not isolated scope in directive your example works fine
https://jsfiddle.net/vorant/waf8rta2/1/

**Second**

if scope in your directive isolated, add this code in directive's controller

```
    $scope.findUrl = function() {
        $scope.$parent.findUrl();
    };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vorant/waf8rta2/2/

**Best way** use `$emit` (directive have to has isolated scope)

directive's controller:

```
    $scope.findUrl = function() {
        $scope.$emit('status:findUrl');
    };
```

application controller:

```
    $scope.$on('status:findUrl',function(){
        $scope.findUrl();
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vorant/waf8rta2/4/